# WebDriverException: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Python script using Selenium can't create an instance of Chrome, despite the versions being correct and a UI being installed.

I've already taken a look at similar threads here, none of which appear to have solved the issue. The code works on Windows - it no longer works once I try to execute it on Linux. My intended goal is for it to open Chrome visually, and as such I am not looking for a solution that involves virtual displays.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/ethan/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
```

I have Google Chrome 75.0.3770.100 installed
I also have ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90

Here is the full traceback from the code:

```
File "cm_update_01.py", line 114, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "cm_update_01.py", line 24, in main
    with open(fetch_file()) as f:
  File "cm_update_01.py", line 75, in fetch_file
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/ethan/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
  File "/home/ethan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/ethan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/ethan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/ethan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ethan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Comment: This is actually not a duplicate issue, but seems to be an issue with ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90. After downgrading to ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 all works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for java, but I think it should work for you to:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4961#issuecomment-346821657
It says that is is a permission issue. Try running your program as root.

Comment: I ran the execution command as root, but the console returned the same error.

Comment: Try adding the `--single-process` flag

Comment: If you look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t, you will find that ChromeDriver was unable to initiate/spawn a new WebBrowser i.e. Chrome Browser session. The arg you are using to stop it only works on Linux, so add these flags too: --disable-extensions, --disable-gpu, disable-infobars, start-maximized.

Comment: I tested the process twice, once with only the secondly mentioned flags (disable-extensions, etc...) and once with the --single-process flag enabled. Both times, the flags did not appear to fix the issue, and the error came back the same as from the original post.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.2.

Comment: What Version python are you using?

Comment: Also try the Firefox drivers. https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: Python 3.6 is my current version